# VoiceOver Headings rotor skips TableHeaderView and focus on section header instead

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I run into a weird issue when using VoiceOver Headings rotor. I have the following view hierarchy:

```
UIButton
UITableView
  UITableView.tableHeaderView
  UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    UITableViewCell
```

Initially when page shows up, VoiceOver focuses on the UIButton. When I use the Headings rotor and swipe down, VoiceOver skips the `tableHeaderView` and focuses on the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` instead. At this time, if I swipe up, it'll focus on the `tableHeaderView`. Both the `tableHeaderView` and `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` has `accessibilityTraits.insert(.header)`. Anyone knows why this happens?

I have created [a github project](https://github.com/XuYan/TableHeaderViewA11y) to repro this issue. It's a single page app and it might help debugging. Thanks!